# VT100 - Unknown characters on the screen

Tags: vt100

I have a problem with the VT100 terminal , because when i tried to install it to a machine , after the restart unknown characters appear on my screen .

Maybe i have touched something wrong on the keyboard , or i don't know ..

I've tried again to do the steps for the install , but the same unknown characters appear on the screen .

http://postimg.org/image/jhpk1csy5/

If anybody knows how i can correct this ...?

Thanks in advance ,

Comment: You could write down the steps for install here, edit your question. And add as much info as possible about the computer you are connecting to etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think most likely the baud rate has changed, and your VT100 terminal expects a different baud rate than the computer expects. Try changing baud settings on either computer or terminal.

Comment: @Andrey, it depends on the terminal how to do it. Some have just one speed, some have little connectors on the back side, and some have a menu system accessible from the keyboard. Also, you should write *what* you connect the Vt100 to. It may be easier to change that instead.

Comment: @Andrey, it could of course be a broken cable or something.

Comment: @Andrey, a tower crane computer? Can't help you there...

Comment: @Andrey, *no*, because you give no information about what kind of vt100 terminal you have, what the installation instructions are that you followed and you let me google that it was a tower crane computer. Basically, you want to me magically know everything about your problem without telling anything.

Comment: @Andrey, that depends on the exact model of your terminal. What is it?

Comment: @Andrey, you should read this:  http://www.boundlessterminals.com/manuals/ADDS%2060%20Users%20Guide.pdf

Comment: @Andrey, no good idea. Maybe some kind of character encoding setting?  You probably should read that manual once more to be sure, but I have no idea.